# Slide UILabel Onto View Controller

Tags: ios, animation, uilabel

I'm trying to move a UILabel from a starting position of off the top of my UIViewController in a smooth slide type animation so that it slides down from the top when the view loads and then stops at a y position for about 10 seconds.  After 10 seconds I want to slide back off the view again.

```
-(void) animateInstructionLabel
{
float newX = 50.0f;
float newY = 100.0f;

[UIView transitionWithView:self.lblInstruction
                  duration:10.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                animations:^(void) {
                    lblInstruction.center = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    // Do nothing
                }];
}
```

But I don't know how to do the 10 second delay and then move back within the method above.  The end result is that I want this to be a label that appears like a notification and then moves off screen again.

Could someone hep me put these pieces described above together?

**EDIT**

I am adding this based on answer below:

```
-(void) animateInstructionLabel
{
float newX = lblInstruction.frame.origin.x;
float newY = 20.0f;

lblInstruction.center = CGPointMake(lblInstruction.frame.origin.x, -20.0f);
lblInstruction.bounds = CGRectMake(lblInstruction.frame.origin.x, -20.0f, 650.0f, 40.0f);

[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^(void) {
                     lblInstruction.center = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f
                                           delay:5.0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                                      animations:^(void) {
                                          lblInstruction.center = CGPointMake(newX, -20);
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                          // Do nothing
                                      }
                      ];
                 }
 ];
}
```

But even though I am setting the label.center off the screen before the animation starts I am seeing that it moves from top left corner of the viewcontroller to the center of the viewcontroller.  It is not keeping the x position that it should be set to before the animation begins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked in case it helps somebody else.  I had to use .frame instead of .center to set the initial position and then the subsequent animation back to that position.

```
-(void) animateInstructionLabel
{

lblInstruction.frame = CGRectMake(lblInstruction.frame.origin.x, -40.0f, 650.0f, 40.0f);
[self.view addSubview:lblInstruction];
lblInstruction.hidden = NO;

float newX = lblInstruction.frame.origin.x;
float newY = 20.0f;

[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^(void) {
                     lblInstruction.center = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f
                                           delay:5.0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                                      animations:^(void) {
                                          lblInstruction.frame = CGRectMake(lblInstruction.frame.origin.x, -40.0f, 650.0f, 40.0f);
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                          lblInstruction.hidden = YES;
                                      }
                      ];
                 }
 ];
}
```

This smoothly makes the label slide down from off the view, stop for 5 seconds and then smoothly moves it back vertically off the view.

Thanks for the previous answers which lead me to the above final solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this after your animation block (oldX,oldY are the old coordinates, before animating the label in):

```
double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.lblInstruction
                      duration:10.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                    animations:^(void) {
                        lblInstruction.center = CGPointMake(oldX, oldY);
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        // Do nothing
                    }];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
-(void) animateInstructionLabel {
    float newX = 50.0f;
    float newY = 100.0f;

    labelInstruction.center = CGPointMake(newX, -20); // start off screen

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0f
                delay:0
                options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                animations:^(void) {
                    lblInstruction.center = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0f
                                delay:10.0
                                options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                                animations:^(void) {
                                    lblInstruction.center = CGPointMake(newX, -20);
                                }
                                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                    // Do nothing
                                }
                    ];
                }
    ];
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding.  This works.  The only issue is my positions.  It moves in from left corner 50.0f down from the top of the ViewController i.e. moves from top left to center of ViewController.  I want it to drop down from the top then slide back up vertically without the left to right movement.

Comment: You need to ensure the label's center is set properly while it is still off of the screen, before the animation starts.

Comment: I have added the following to try to set the position before the animation starts but it does not seem to set this.  e.g. lblInstruction.center = CGPointMake(lblInstruction.frame.origin.x, -20.0f);
lblInstruction.bounds = CGRectMake(lblInstruction.frame.origin.x, -20.0f, 650.0f, 40.0f);  but it still moves from left top corner to the new position then back to the top left corner.  The exact position I have set it to is -20.0f (x) 187.0f (y) on my xib.

Comment: See my updated answer. I now set the label's center before the animation starts.

Comment: Setting the center doesn't seem to work for me.  the animation still starts from the top left corner.  I have also tried setting the lblInstruction.center = CGPointMake(187.0f, -20.0f); which is the same as on the .xib as a starting position.